# adding a hashtable to an array for submission to azure machine learning

Tags: arrays, powershell, azure, machine-learning, hashtable

bear with me, this is gonna take some explaining!
I need to write some code which allows me to submit to azure machine learning, for testing usage.

the format is 
dictionary, containing an array of dictionaries which are the use cases.
so the following code

```
# create the usage case to submit
$usecase1 = @{
    "Father" = "dad";
    "Mother" = "mum";
}

# its possible to submit multiple so wrap in an array
$inputArray =@()
$inputArray += $usecase1

# create the dictionary, add the array in
$inputsDictionary = @{}        
$inputsDictionary.Add("input1", $input1Array) 

# convert to json for submission
$data = $inp | ConvertTo-Json
$data 

invoke-webrequest -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $data -    ContentType 'application/json' -verbose
```

when we run this, it outputs the data object as

```
{
    "inputs":  {
               "input1":  [
                          "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                          ]
           }
}
```

which isnt right. i need to insert the hashtable as values.

anyone seen this before or have an example of how to do it that they can link me to?

Comment: Use the `-Depth` parameter to avoid flattening the hierarchy early: `$inp |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10`

Comment: brilliant. thanks so much. do you want to repost as a solution?